# Customisation of longtable caption

Tags: captions, longtable, scalebox, toptesi

I have to change the caption style of a `longtable` to obtain the same style of a normal `table`;

i.e. to get:

[image],

instead of:

[image].

In addition, I'd like to reduce the size of the `longtable` without changing the dimensions of the caption. I found some solutions that in the case of my document give me errors.

Any idea? Thanks.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,cucitura,oldstyle,autoretitolo,classica,greek]{toptesi}
        \usepackage[or]{teubner}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{wrapfig}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{tabu}
        \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
        \usepackage{fixltx2e}
        \usepackage{import}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
        \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
        \usepackage{notoccite}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage{enumerate}
        \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{listings}
        \usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9
\english

    \begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \caption{Test.}
    \label{t:test}\\
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline\hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
    \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &   \\
    \hline\hline
    \end{longtable}

\begin{table}[ht] \centering
\caption{Test.}
\label{t:RP}
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\toprule
\textbf{...} & \textbf{...} \\ \hline
 .& \\ \hline
 &  \\ \hline
 & \multirow{6}{*}{...} \\ \cline{1-1}
 &  \\ \cline{1-1}
 &  \\ \cline{1-1}
 &  \\ \cline{1-1}
 &  \\ \cline{1-1}
 &  \\ \hline
. & ... \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The template toptesi is: https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/italian-thesis-template-(toptesi).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I'd like to resize the longtable without changing the dimensions of the caption."

Comment: I have to reduce the size only of the table. I'm using `Overleaf`.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "I have to reduce the size only of the table." Are you talking about the horizontal dimension, the vertical dimension, both, or neither?

Comment: I want a result similar to what you get with `\scalebox` as in the second table of the code (horizontal and vertical dimension).

Answer (score 1):

The `toptesi` document class file and the associated file `toptesi.sty` redefine the properties of the `\caption` command. Unfortunately, they do so in a way that fails to modify the default properties of the `\caption` command that's provided by the `longtable` environment (and which, AFAICT, mostly replicates the properties of the `\caption` command provided by the "standard" LaTeX document classes, such as `article` and `report`).

Rather than hack the code provided by `longtable.sty`, I suggest you load the `caption` package and issue the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{toptesi}{.\quad}
\captionsetup{labelsep=toptesi,font=small}
```

Comment: This solution works but returns some _warnings_ (i.e. _Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation._)

Comment: @MiKaEl - It's a warning message, not an error message. Anyway, if you look at the code in `toptesi.sty`, you'll see that the document class takes care not to interfere with the `caption` package.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Just to know, it gives also this type of warning message: _Appendices/AppendixC/AppendixC.tex, line 200 Float too large for page by 0.59935pt on input line 200._ . I use latex a lot, but only with easier online compilers; so I do not have a rigorous preparation. I hope these warning messages do not conflict with other parts of the document.

Comment: @MiKaEl - LaTeX (and TeX) can be very fussy with warning messages. If the vertical size of a table exceeds `\textheight` by a mere 0.6pt, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you. If you can let me know how to make the `longtable` smaller without changing the caption, like using `\scalebox`.

Comment: @MiKaEl - I assume that by "smaller", you mean "occupy less vertical space".  `\scalebox` only works with objects that are confined to a single page; hence, it cannot work with a `longtable` environment. Try (a) placing the `longtable` inside a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` pair of statements, and (b) inserting the directive `\renecommand\arraystretch{0.99}`.

Comment: I want to reduce the horizontal and vertical size. It works very well using `\footnotesize` but in this case you have also a change to the caption. So I'd like to get a similar result, without changing the caption.

Comment: The last solution you told me returns the following error: 
  \renecommand\arraystretch{0.99}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. Maybe I need to add one `\usepackage`.

Comment: @MiKaEl - Sorry for the typo: The correct command name is `\renewcommand`, not `\renecommand`. My apologies.

Comment: @MiKaEl - If you want to change the font size of the caption to `\footnotesize`, all you need to do is change `\captionsetup{labelsep=toptesi,font=small}` to `\captionsetup{labelsep=toptesi,font=footnotesize}`.

Comment: I want to reduce the horizontal and vertical size **only of the table**. A good result could be achievable using  `\footnotesize` but in this case you have also a change to the caption and I don't want to change the caption. I want to change the size of the table without touching the caption. Now your latter solution works but it seems to reduce only the vertical size of the table.

Comment: I found a solution. In addition to the above answer, for horizontal resizing, just use: `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}`,  inside the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.